# Effect of network transfer over cpu

Tags: c, networking, cpu-usage, data-transfer

I have a project for which i need to minimize the impact of sending / receiving computed data over the network.

In my configuration, a (small) grid of computers will compute a large number of values (matrix_i^n, each machine having a large set of i's assigned). These values will then be send over the network to another computer depending on properties of the computed value (on average, every computer receives the same number of values).

I would like to optimize the time needed to compute these values (up to a power m, predetermined). In oder to do this, i need to choose the best way to transfer the intermediary results:

- Precompute everything then exchange all the values to the right computer
- Send every value to the right computer as soon as it is available
- Hybrid solution where small packs of data are exchanged during the computation

Since network transfers are very slow, I have the feeling that I should start transferring data asap but i'm not sure that the overhead on the CPU (handling more exceptions, hence more work for the scheduler) would not blow the performance of the computation.

Do you know documentation i could rely on or a good benchmark suite (written in C) i could use to make some test by myself ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CPU usage for networking is generally determined by the amount of I/O calls you make. If you can, design your app in a way that lets you tweak your buffer size easily so that you can test. Using enough buffering, 10gb/s is no sweat.

What OS are you using? I doubt you'll need it, but Windows 8 has [Registered I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740642%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is designed for extremely low latency and CPU usage.

Comment: I am using a unix environment. The question here is: What are the buffer size i should use in order to use the cpu at full speed and the network as much as possible so that the cpu looses the less time sending things on the network? and: Should i buffer and send while computing or send everything after computation (in the case too many I/O calls are made)? My question might be to much specific to the problem. I guess i'll have to test everything anyway.